# Estimating Beta distribution parameter from Pert distribution ones

Tags: beta-distribution, hyperparameter, parameterization

The Pert distribution is a modification of a Beta distribution defined by 3 parameters (a, b, c).

Is it possible to specify the underlying Beta from those 3 parameters, transforming them into the usual $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a four parameter beta distribution $beta(\alpha, \beta, a, c)$ with a and c being the minimum and maximum value of the desired distribution and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ shape parameters, Vose (2008) uses:

$$
\begin{aligned}
  \alpha &= \frac{(\mu - a)(2b-a-c)}{(b-\mu)(c-a)} \\
  \beta  &= \frac{\alpha (c - \mu)}{\mu - a} \\
  \text{with } \mu &= \frac{a + 4b + c}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$

Davis (2008) suggested to use

$$
\begin{aligned}
  \alpha &= \frac{2(c+4b-5a)}{3(c-a)} \cdot 
            \left[ 1+4(\frac{(b-a)(c-b)}{(c-a)^2}) \right] \\
  \beta  &= \frac{2(5c-4b-a)}{3(c-a)} \cdot 
            \left[ 1+4(\frac{(b-a)(c-b)}{(c-a)^2}) \right]
\end{aligned}
$$

This way Davis makes sure that the beta distributions we get with these parameters actually exhibit means and variances as specified by the PERT mean and variance formulas, which are:

$$ 
\text{mean} = \frac{c + 4b + a}{6} \\
\text{var}  = (\frac{c-a}{6})^2
$$

**References**

Davis, Ron. 2008. “Teaching Note - Teaching Project Simulation in Excel Using PERT-BetaDistributions.” INFORMS Transactions on Education 8 (3): 139–48. https://doi.org/10.1287/ited.1080.0013.

Vose, D. 2008. Risk Analysis: A Quantitative Guide. 3rd ed. John Wiley & Sons. https://books.google.de/books?id=9CaoAqaRcVwC.